# django reverse lookup foreignkey not working

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I want to get a specific `Video` object and then find all of the `Rating` objects that are associated with it using ForeignKey reverse lookup as described in the docs.

I have models:

```
class Video(models.Model):
 ...
    rating_int = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=CHOICES, name='rating_int')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Rating(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey('Video', related_name='video', null=True)
```

and views:

```
def video_ratings(request):
    vid_rate = Video.objects.get(pk=1)
    ratings_of_video = vid_rate.rating_set.all()
    context = {
        'vid_rate': vid_rate, 'ratings_video': ratings_of_video
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

When I try to run this I get an error `'Video' object has no attribute 'rating_set'`

But when i read the django docs it tells me when you do a reverse lookup you need to use this `_set.all()` command. I am not sure what is missing here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have specified related_name in your foreign key loopkup. so rating_set should not work now.

You can lookup like

```
ratings_of_video = vid_rate.video.all()
```

A better naming convention will be to use `ratings` in your related_name

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey('Video', related_name='ratings', null=True)
```

and then query like

```
ratings_of_video = vid_rate.ratings.all()
```

Comment: ahhh that was the issue! Did not see that in the docs, thanks for the tip too

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue, I was stuck on this for far too long